# I need to pass data from component to another?

Tags: vuejs2

**I have two components (News component and News-Details component, I need to transfer title, description and image from news to detailed page any idea?**

```
**News Component**
<template>
    <div class="container mt-5 mb-5">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="text-center mb-3">Our News</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center" v-for="newss in news">
            <img :src="newss.imgSrc" class="img-fluid"  style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
            <h2>{{newss.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{newss.paragraph}}</p>
            <router-link to="/news-details">
                <button class="btn btn-success"  >Read More</button>
            </router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        data : function () {
            return{
                news:[
                    {
                        title : 'News One',
                        paragraph : 'News Description One',
                        imgSrc: 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg'
                    },
                    {
                        title : 'News Two',
                        paragraph : 'News Description Two',
                        imgSrc: 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg'
                    },
                    {
                        title : 'News Three',
                        paragraph : 'News Description Three',
                        imgSrc: 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg'
                    }

                ]
            }
        },

     }
</script>


**News Details Component**
<template>
    <div class="container mt-5 mb-5">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="text-center mb-3">News Details</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <img :src="imgSrc" class="img-fluid"  style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
                <h2>{{title}}</h2>
                <p>{{paragraph}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            title : String,
            paragraph: String,
            imgSrc: String
        }

    }
</script>
```

**I have two components (News component and News-Details component, I need to transfer title, description and image from news to detailed page any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to transfer content through components.

Firstly
through $emit(), you can catch a change in your parent component, and you can pass down the change with prop to your other child component.

```
methods:{
 changeHandler: function(){
  this.$emit('info', {title, image,description})
 }
}
```

in your child component do the above, in your parents do the below

```
<news @info="info"></news>
<news-detail info="info"></news-detail>
```

You have not provided how the  components are structured, and the hierarchies so I do not know if this will work for you.

Secondly, through vuex

you can `commit()` the values, and access it through `getters[]`

thirdly, through event bus, similar to the first one but with a central control.

Comment: This is my main Component

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I have the components separate, i need to know how i can send the data after i click on Read More button In news to news details i know the emit but i don't know how to use